# Removing a view controller from memory when instantiating a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

In my app, I am instantiating new view controllers instead of using segues because it looks better in animations as a result, my views keep running in the background. This causes large memory leaks.

My code to go back to the main screen is:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc  : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This view controller is still active in the background and therefore shouldn't be instantiated again. How do I do this.

When I close my view controller using the above code, it also does not unload it, it keeps running in the background. How do I make it unload as soon as the screen disappears.

I have tried doing

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
    view = nil
}
```

However this does not work properly. How do I properly destroy a view controller from memory when exiting a view controller in this manner.

Comment: You can't remove a view controller from within itself (i.e. viewDidDisappear) - what you need to do is to remove all references to it, at which point `ARC` will deallocate it. If the only place you reference it is when you create it above, then simply calling `dismissViewController` on whatever has presented it, will allow your viewcontroller to be deallocated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need only to use:

**EDIT Swift 4.2**

```
self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
```

The rest of work is doing by [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting)

To help you during your debug you can add also this code:

```
 if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
        if let viewControllers = window.rootViewController?.children {
            for viewController in viewControllers {
                print(viewController.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put dismissViewControllerAnimated()? Should I put it in the view controller that I am closing? That doesn't seem to work. Doesn't bring me back to a new View Controller

Comment: Make a button in your viewController, call it DISMISS, connect an ibaction for touchupinside and insert in this method the dismiss line

Comment: **Swift 3.1** :  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: In which viewController do you write the code?  The source/previous/earlier one?  Or the current/second/later one now in focus?

Comment: @Cindeselia The current in focus

Answer (score 2):

An important reason for this problem is related to the memory management!

if you have 'strong reference' or 'delegate' or 'closure' or other things like this, and you didn't managed these objects, your view controller has strong reference and never be closed.

you should get 'deinit' callback in view controller after than viewDidDisappear called. if 'deinit' not called so your view controller still is alive and it has strong reference.