# Swift / How to properly dismiss a rootViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In one of my views I'm creating a rootViewController with:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        let nav = RootDJasUserVC(rootViewController: pageController)

        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

**Withing** a View of `RootDJasUserVC` I'm calling  another function to get to another rootViewController:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        let nav = RootVC(rootViewController: pageController)

        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Not I want to go back to `RootDJasUserVC`, but I want `RootDJasUserVC` to be completely new loaded. Currently when I'm going back to `RootDJasUserVC` (with the same function as in the first code block), `viewDidLoad` will not be executed, because the view is obviously still loaded somewhere.

How to I properly "dismiss" a rootViewController like that, to have it "reloaded"? Help is very appreciated.

PS. What I would like to do is something like this within `RootDJasUserVC`:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

But nothings happening when I execute that.

PPS. Those rootViewControllers are sublasses of `UINavigationController`

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920859/removing-a-view-controller-from-memory-when-instantiating-a-new-view-controller

Comment: the solution on your link doesnt work for me, even tho it is similar. i want to dismiss a "rootViewController", nut just a viewController. if i hit a button declared to that method, it's not working. ->nothing happens

Comment: @DavidSeek see the edited code

Comment: @DavidSeek  
check edit 3 of the answer

Comment: @DavidSeek see the last edit of my answer, hope it helps u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to change root view controller every time, if u want to u can present the view controller at any point of time for example, lets take your code,

in the below code u are just setting the root view controller as `RootDJasUserVC`,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    let nav = RootDJasUserVC(rootViewController: pageController)

    appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

if u want to show new controller there is no need to change the root view controller `RootDJasUserVC` just present the view controller for example,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    let nav = RootVC(rootViewController: pageController) //check with simply presenting the view controller if u don't want navigation controller

    //appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    //let rootVc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: false, completion: {

        })
    //no need of below code
    //appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
    //appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

once u present then, u can dismiss the view controller

using `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` once the view controller is dismissed, `viewWillAppear` and  `viewDidlAppear` methods are called, use this to refresh the `RootDJasUserVC`

**Edit 2**

i don't no what exactly going on, but if u want to load new root view controller do like below,

just add a method in app delegate to load new root view controller

```
func loadNewRootViewController()
{
    let controller:RootDJasUserVC = RootDJasUserVC(nibName: "RootDJasUserVC", bundle: nil)
    let aNavController:UINavigationController? = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    self.window?.rootViewController = aNavController;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

above method load the fresh new root view controller, all u need to call it once the dismiss of the view controller lets say after u dismiss the of the view controller

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { 
        //change the root hear
       let appdelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       appdelegate.loadNewRootViewController() //load new fresh root view controller
}
```

**Edit 3**

```
 self.navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false)  { 
        //change the root hear
       let appdelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       appdelegate.loadNewRootViewController() //load new fresh root view controller
}
```

**Edit 4**

while showing the second view controller,
show `pageController`

```
 let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
 let nav = RootVC(rootViewController: pageController) //check with simply presenting the view controller if u don't want navigation controller

 //appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 //let rootVc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!
 self.presentViewController(nav, animated: false, completion: {

  })
```

it will show the new controller as u said, in this class u need to call dismiss method for example,

in the second that is presented view controller, u can dismiss like below

```
 self.navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false)  { 
    //change the root hear
   let appdelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   appdelegate.loadNewRootViewController() //load new fresh root view controller
 }
```

hear `self.navigationController` should not be nil because while presenting u set a `RootVC()` it is the navigation controller.

Comment: but i need a new rootViewController. rootViewController is a navigationBarController, setting up an array of viewControllers within viewDidLoad. My Problem is, that the content of THOSE viewControllers WITHIN the navigationBarController needs to be refreshed. But putting it into viewWillAppear for example doesn't solve it, because the user will swipe fast through those viewController contents if you are WITHIN RootDJasUserVC, you don't want the content to be constantly re-loaded

Comment: and your code throws nil on: `let rootVc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!` whil unwrapping optional

Comment: it should have a root view controller `RootDJasUserVC` while care showing second controller `nav`

Comment: I'm copy pasting your code and get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: RootDJasUserVC is rootViewController and I want to go back to RootVC

Comment: i just give an example, in the code where u are showing the new view controller, just present the view controller see the edit

Comment: the edit code is working. but whats the difference? the content within the views of RootDJasUserVC is still loaded

Comment: dismissViewController is not working, RootDJasUserVC as well as RootVC are subclasses of NavigationController, maybe that's why?

Comment: edit 3: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: it is due to while presenting the second view controller, u are directly presenting it, thats wy navigation is nil, and any way if u present the view controller it should work for dismiss also

Comment: can u show how u are dismissing the second view controller

Comment: i am now calling your `loadNewRootViewController` func from edit3, changed to `let controller:RootVC = RootVC(nibName: "RootVC", bundle: nil)`. called within `RootDJasUserVC`class called by your code from edit3

Comment: the function is called by button press on a UIBarButtonItem at RootDJasUserVCclass

Comment: i have done it exactly like in edit 4, but `self.navigationController`is still nil.

Comment: do you think it affects the logic?

Comment: `RootVC` is a `SwipeViewController` and this is a subclass of `UINavigationController`

Comment: if it is nil then use just `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122887/discussion-between-shan-and-david-seek).

Answer (score 1):

Put your reload code in `viewWillAppear` of the `RootDJasUserVC` (`viewDidLoad` only run once), it will be called everytime your you go back to that view, i believe this is the better way than creating new instance of it

Comment: not working. within RootDJasUserVC, an Array of viewControllers will be created and initialized. that only works in viewDidLoad, app crashes with this in viewDidLoad.

Comment: also all the views have tableViews that will be reloaded everytime the user swipes through the app, if the content will be loaded within viewWillAppear

Comment: I cant understand what you are saying....have you tried putting your array creation code in viewWillAppear yet?

Comment: I have, but `RootDJasUserVC` is a controller of the custom class "SwipeViewController". that class needs the viewControllerArray to be instanziated within viewDidLoad. App crashes if it's within viewWillAppear